# Running a shell command from Node.js without buffering output

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm trying to launch a shell command from Node.js, *without* redirecting that command's input and output -- just like shelling out to a command using a shell script, or using Ruby's `system` command. If the child process wants to write to STDOUT, I want that to go straight to the console (or get redirected, if my Node app's output was redirected).

Node doesn't seem to have any straightforward way to do this. It looks like the only way to run another process is with `child_process`, which *always* redirects the child process's input and output to pipes. I can write code to accept data from those pipes and write it to my process's STDOUT and STDERR, but if I do that, the APIs force me to sacrifice some flexibility.

I want two features:

- Shell syntax. I want to be able to pipe output between commands, or run Windows batch files.
- Unlimited output. If I'm shelling out to a compiler and it wants to generate megabytes of compiler warnings, I want them all to scroll across the screen (until the user gets sick of it and hits Ctrl+C).

It looks like Node wants to force me choose between those two features.

- If I want an unlimited amount of output, I can use [`child_process.spawn`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) and then do `child.stdout.on('data', function(data) { process.stdout.write(data); });` and the same thing for `stderr`, and it'll happily pipe data until the cows come home. Unfortunately, `spawn` doesn't support shell syntax.
- If I want shell syntax, I can use [`child_process.exec`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback). But `exec` insists on buffering the child process's STDOUT and STDERR for me and giving them to me all at the end, and it limits the size of those buffers (configurable, 200K by default). I can still hook the `on('data')` events, if I want to see the output as it's generated, but `exec` will still add the data to its buffers too. When the amount of data exceeds the predefined buffer size, `exec` will terminate the child process.

(There's also [`child_process.execFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback), which is the *worst* of both worlds from a flexibility standpoint: no shell syntax, but you still have to cap the amount of output you expect.)

Am I missing something? **Is there any way to just shell out to a child process in Node, and *not* redirect its input and output?** Something that supports shell syntax and doesn't crap out after a predefined amount of output, just like is available in shell scripts, Ruby, etc.?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: same issue, 'until the cows come home' thanks, for that, made my day after 10h of work

Answer (score 48):

You can inherit stdin/out/error streams via `spawn` argument so you don't need to pipe them manually:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('ls', [], { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

Use shell for shell syntax - for bash it's `-c` parameter to read script from string:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var shellSyntaxCommand = 'ls -l | grep test | wc -c';
spawn('sh', ['-c', shellSyntaxCommand], { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

To summarise:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
function shspawn(command) {
   spawn('sh', ['-c', command], { stdio: 'inherit' });
} 

shspawn('ls -l | grep test | wc -c');
```

Comment: That's a little simpler than having to pipe the output manually, but it still doesn't support shell syntax. Sure, I can [manually choose a shell to invoke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9779382/87399), but then my code isn't cross-platform.

Comment: if you want to get stdout and stderr, replace 'inherit' by 'pipe'

Answer (score 17):

You can replace `exec` by `spawn` and use the shell syntax simply with:

```
const {spawn} = require ('child_process');
const cmd = 'ls -l | grep test | wc -c';
const p = spawn (cmd, [], {shell: true});

p.stdout.on ('data', (data) => {
  console.log (data.toString ());
});
```

The magic is just `{shell: true}`.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used it, but I've seen this library: https://github.com/polotek/procstreams

It you'd do this. The `.out()` automatically pipes to  the process's stdin/out.

```
var $p = require('procstreams');
$p('cat lines.txt').pipe('wc -l').out();
```

If doesn't support shell syntax, but that's pretty trivial I think.

```
var command_str = "cat lines.txt | wc -l";
var cmds = command_str.split(/\s?\|\s?/);
var cmd = $p(cmds.shift());
while(cmds.length) cmd = cmd.pipe(cmds.shift());
cmd
  .out()
  .on('exit', function() {
    // Do whatever
  });
```

Comment: I just tried it, and it doesn't support Windows batch files, which is really the main reason I want shell support. Lots of originally-Unix tools (e.g. Rake) are implemented using batch files on Windows, and I want to be able to invoke them from Node.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't support"? It crashes, says batch file not found, locks and executes forever?

Comment: `CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the file specified.` Same error as `child_process.spawn` when you try to run a batch file, because batch files aren't executable (directly); if I try to run `$p('rake').out();`, it goes looking for a binary executable named `rake.exe` or `rake.com`, fails to find them, and errors out. You need the shell (`cmd.exe`) if you want to run batch files.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in the [node docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) for the child_process module:

Example of detaching a long-running process and redirecting its output to a file:

```
 var fs = require('fs'),
     spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
     out = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a'),
     err = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a');

 var child = spawn('prg', [], {
   detached: true,
   stdio: [ 'ignore', out, err ]
 });

 child.unref();
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? You're showing how to redirect output to a file; the question was very specifically about *not* redirecting output.

Comment: I think you're right. I obviously misread the question the first time. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is

```
spawn("echo bla", { stdio: "inherit", shell: true });
```

This is both piping stdio to the current process and using the `shell` option to support any command string.