# execute a terminal command using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Iam trying to execute a terminal command using node.js spawn

```
tshark -i 3 -Y "ipp contains 02:00:00:00" -T pdml > ggggg.xml
```

for that am using the code

```
var args = ['-i', '3',
              '-Y',         
             "ipp contains 02:00:00:00" ,'-T','pdml','>','ggggg.xml'];
 

console.log(args)

var child = spawn("tshark", args, {cwd: workDir});
        child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
          
          console.log(data.toString())        
        });
      
        child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
          console.log('stdout: ' + data);
           
        });

        child.on('close', function(code) {
          console.log('closing code: ' + code);
              
        });
```

`But it treated greater than` >`as string`">" and
getting output as

```
tshark: Invalid capture filter "> gggggg.xml" 
    
    That string isn't a valid capture filter (syntax error).
    See the User's Guide for a description of the capture filter syntax.
```

How can i use `>` without string

Comment: '> ggggg.xml' is shell syntax for redirecting stdout to file. You should use proper options of spawn http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio or use `child_process.exec` which will call shell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a shell command from Node.js without buffering output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777215/running-a-shell-command-from-node-js-without-buffering-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use file streams to put all output from spawned `hark` to `g.xml`.
Example:

```
// don't need ">" in args
var args = [' 02:00:00:00' ,'-s','pdml'],
    logStream = fs.createWriteStream('./xml');

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    child = spawn('tshark', args);

child.stdout.pipe(logStream);
child.stderr.pipe(logStream);

child.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Because of `child` here is a stream, you can just pipe it into your logged file stream.

Comment: yes one more thing..ur coding is working..but it did not output the valid xml file....some attributes are missing

Comment: Try to play with options: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

Comment: I will get the full xml file when i manully exit the running terminal using ctrl+C ..but in code i tried to exit the process and killed the child process but not getting the full output in that case also

Comment: Tried using 'exit' event instead of 'close' for `child`?

Comment: But it does not goes inside 'exit' event or 'close' event..that is the main problem..also i cannot identify the process is completed or not and i quil the terminal by ctrl+c command

Comment: @Psl if it is still topical, please provide an gist example with real data that reproduce this problem. Past a link on this gist here. I'll try to play with that.