# Run block of bash / shell in node's spawn

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, child-process

I'm writing a command line utility, and I need stdout to write to TTY or use `{stdio: 'inherit'}` I've been getting by with `exec` but it's not going to cut it. I need way for a spawn process to execute the following echo commands below. I know that spawn spins up a child process with a given command, and you pass in arguments, but I need it to just take a line-separated string of commands like this. This is what I'm currently feeding to exec. Is this possible?

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn
const child = spawn(`
echo "alpha"
echo "beta"
`)

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`)
});

child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`)
});

child.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`)
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a shell command from Node.js without buffering output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777215/running-a-shell-command-from-node-js-without-buffering-output)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`spawn()` does *not* involve a shell, so in order to have it execute shell commands, you must invoke the shell executable *explicitly* and pass the shell command(s) as an *argument*:

```
const child = spawn('/bin/sh', [ '-c',  `
echo "alpha"
echo "beta"
` ])
```

Note I've used `/bin/sh` rather than `/bin/bash` in an effort to make your command run on a wider array of [Unix-like] platforms.
All major POSIX-like shells accept a command string via the `-c` option.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed, thanks so much!